# ICC 11.1 has strange behaviour regarding PTHREADS on ia64

Tags: c++, pthreads, icc

I'm working on a ia64-machine using ICC 11.1. The following program compiles nicely:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << PTHREAD_STACK_MIN << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with `icc test.cpp -o test`

BUT when I change the contents of the file to to:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);
    return 0;
}
```

I suddenly get:

> icc -c test.cpp -o test.o test.cpp(6):
>   error: identifier "PTHREAD_STACK_MIN"
>   is undefined
>           printf("%d\n", PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);
>                          ^
>
> compilation aborted for test.cpp (code
>   2)

Can anyone explain to me why? Or more importantly: how I can work around this issue so that the second code example will also compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's easy: you forgot to include `<limits.h>` where the `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN` is supposed to be declared (as per [POSIXv6/SUSv3](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html)).

And from the error one can conclude that `<iostream>` internally also includes the `<limits.h>` why in C++ mode the error doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was helpful. :)
Unfortunately in the code that this minimal example was extrapolated from, <limits.h> is included but I still get an error about PTHREAD_STACK_MIN being undefined. Oh well, I guess I'll have to dig deeper, but thanks anyways! :)

Comment: @Tom: It would have helped if you specified your OS. HP-UX? Linux? The headers are OS dependent, not compiler. Try to run the file through preprocessor with max verbosity (in gcc: gcc -E -dD test.cpp > test.i) and see what's going wrong. Also try to give `-mpthreads` (or its ICC's analog) command line option to your compiler (shouldn't matter in the case, but what if).

Comment: Oh, sorry... the OS is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (ia64). Well, thanks to Dummy00001's answer, both minimal examples run now. However I am having problems compiling a library I need, where the examples were just extrapolated from. But I guess at this point I'll just contact the devs in charge of that library. Cheers :)